# Max number of players in multiplayer

Tags: torchlight-2

How many players can play simultaneously in a multiplayer game ? Is it the same for both internet and LAN games ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The maximum players in a non-modded TL2 game is 6 players.  However, an official mod by Runic Games extends this limit to 8.  The limit is the same in both internet and LAN games.

Keep in mind that the host of the game (the creator) can set a smaller limit on the number of players allowed in the game, if he/she chooses.

Mod for Steam version: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=135166277
Mod for non-Steam version: http://www.runicgamesfansite.com/vbdownloads.php?do=download&downloadid=380